# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities is invalid for iOS application

Tags: ios, app-store, info.plist

I'm trying to upload an iOS application to iTunes Connect, however every time I attempt to upload the application I get the following message:

> Performance - 2.3
>
> We were unable to install the app. The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
>   key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not
>   install.
>
> Next Steps
>
> Please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it
>   contains only the attributes required for your app features or the
>   attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes
>   specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required
>   and false if they must not be present on the device.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities.

My application requires the device to have a camera as it involves reading a QR code.

The following is my info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>still-camera</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>pw.whatsyourwifi.ios</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>5</string>
    <key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key>
    <false/>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have looked at a number of resources provided by Apple such as:
[Expected App Behaviours](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW5)
[List of Possible Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)

Any help is appreciated, just don't know what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, this was resolved for me when I simply replied to the app rejection stating that my plist file was correct per the docs (assuming yours is correct to your app and the docs). They accepted me.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` must be a dictionary, not an array; the capability is used as a key in the dictionary, and the value must be set to a boolean true or false to indicate whether the device must have the capability, or must *not* have the capability.

(The utility of prohibiting capabilities in an app is a little questionable. I'm not sure why it'd make sense to have an app that would refuse to install on a device with a camera, for instance. But that's what Apple put in there, so…)

In your case, this would look like:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<dict>
    <key>still-camera</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: Apple developer docs state it can be an Array or Dictionary: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3